# Accessing the variables of a parent widget via a button

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm trying to implement a default button. This button should access strings of the parent widget which is a dialog box which the button is found on.  I pasted the relevant parts of the code below. What I want is to be able to place strings to their corresponding lineEdit's when default values is clicked. For example pulse_string goes to ui->pulse_freq and nr_pulsestring goes into ui->nr_pulses etc.

```
#include "settings.h"
#include "ui_settings.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QSpinBox>

int pulse_freq = 25000;
int nr_pulses = 10;
int samp_freq = 150000;
int nr_samples = 2000;
int gain = 32;
int accumulate = 1;
int acq_start = 0;

Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)

{
    QString pulse_string, nr_pulsestring, sampfreq_string, nr_samplestring, gain_string;
    QString accumulate_string, acq_string;

}

Settings::~Settings()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Settings::on_Default_Values_clicked()
{
    ui->pulse_freq->setText("25000");
    ui->nr_pulses->setText("10");
    ui->samp_freq->setText("150000");
    ui->nr_samples->setText("2000");
    ui->gain->setText("32");
    ui->accumulate->setText("1");
    ui->acq_start->setText("0");
}
```

Comment: Use "this->parentWidget()" to access the parent, cast it, call a method to set values

Comment: Did you mean something like this:                                     `<ui->pulse_freq->setText(this->parentWidget(pulse_string));>`

Comment: Sort of: added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something looking like follows:

```
ui->pulse_freq->setText(QString("%1").arg(pulse_freq));
```

Since it seems you are only using numbers it would be better using a spinbox to insert values, so you dont have to check if an input is a valid number, etc.

Comment: It couldn't recognise MyparentW so I changed it to Settings which is the object name. The getDefault part was not recognised as an action in Qt so I still couldn't access any of the strings I wanted                                                    `void Settings::on_Default_Values_clicked()
{
    Settings* obj = (Settings*)parentWidget();`

Comment: Whats the classname of your parent? You have to cast it to that specific class/obj... Moreover you have to include the header file of your parent within the settings.cpp file

Comment: I believe the parent is the dialog box. The class name is settings (what I called the dialog box). I deduced that based off this part of the code above       `<Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)>`    I've added the relevant headers.  The initial code I pasted is what I'm using. Could I make the dialog box public? Would that make all it's variables accessible externally? Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah ok... Now I got i think... So you are on the right way... Simply use: ui->pulse_freq->setText(QString("%1"). arg(pulse_freq);

Comment: So pls upvote and mark as correct answer... Answer adjusted and a hint added

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to upvote or mark as correct.

Comment: Mark as solved should always be possible, for up-voting you're right